# Trouble getting json from API with angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Trying to pull in some data using angular and an API. Obviously I'm quite new to this.

My custom service:

```
readIp.service('ip', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.getIP = function(ip) {
        var ipData = $resource("http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=getip", {
            callback : "JSON_CALLBACK" 
        }, { 
            get : { 
                method: "JSONP" 
            }
        });
        return ipData.get({ getip: ip });
    }
}]);
```

From my controller:

```
$scope.getIP = ip.getIP($scope.getip);
```

HTML:

```
<strong>Your IP is:</strong>&nbsp;{{ getIP.ip }}
```

I'm getting an error currently:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getip is not defined
```

as the API shows up as: getip({"ip":"###.###.##.##"}); from the source.

Comment: First you declare getIP (capital) and then you try to use getip (no capital).
Javascript is case sensitive... if these are different variables, use different names to avoid errors

Answer (score 0):

Your service isn't properly defined. It should return an object that contains your getIp method. try something along the lines of :

```
readIp.factory('ip', ['$resource', function($resource){
  return {
    getIP: function(ip) {
      // your code goes here
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in place of above code. Hope you have already added ngResource module.

`readIp.factory('ip',['$resource',function($resource){
    return $resource('http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=getip', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}}
    });
}])`